# numberplate validation problems in python

Tags: python

I am doing a practice assessment for school and me and my friends have been having problems with this code

```
   if len(numberplate)==7:
        if numberplate[0].isalpha:
            if numberplate[1].isalpha:
                if numberplate[2].isnumeric:
                    if numberplate[3].isnumeric:
                        if numberplate[4].isalpha:
                            if numberplate[5].isalpha:
                                if numberplate[6].isalpha:
```

What it should do:

- if the `numberplate` is `GT45HOK` then `print('valid input')`
- if it is `GT5HYKU` then it should `print('invalid input')`

But because it's 7 letters long it `print('valid input')`

Comment: `holy ____`. thats a lot of `if's`. use `regex`

Comment: Or at the very least use `and`. The key issue here is that you aren't *calling* the methods - you need more parentheses.

Comment: @YvesDaoust yes, and that's not a standard UK numberplate

Comment: Note that `"GT45HOK"[0].isalpha` gives you `<built-in method isalpha of str object at 0x0244D668>`...

Comment: Actually this code report valid for any 7-letters string.

Comment: @sam2090 That's all well and good, but the OP says this is a practice assessment for school. I suspect understanding and use of regular expressions comes quite a bit later (if at all!).

Comment: @Phylogenesis agreed. just trying to lighten up the mood of serious commenters. usually for a question like this, its downvoted and closed very quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can read in *jonrsharpe*'s comments, your code doesn't work because `isalpha` doesn't return the result you want here. `isalpha()` is what you need, this returns the `boolean` you're after.

*However*, I would use a [regular expression](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/regular-expressions) here. It matches 2 capital alphabetic letters, 2 numbers, and 3 more capital letters.

```
import re

numberplate = 'GT45HOK'
r = re.compile('[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{3}')
if r.match(numberplate):
    print 'valid input'
else:
    print 'invalid input'
```

Comment: This will work, but: 1. `\d{2}` is simpler than `[0-9]{2}`; and 2. it doesn't actually tell the OP what their problem is.

Comment: I had \d but I imagined this to be better understandable for someone that never used regex before.

I added the actual answer to his question to my answer, with credits to you ofc.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I sounded harsh in the comments.
Try this

```
def isValidNumberPlate(number_plate):
    if len(number_plate) != 7:
        return False

    if (number_plate[0:2].isalpha() and number_plate[2:4].isdigit() and number_plate[4:].isalpha()):
        return True

    return False

print isValidNumberPlate('GT45HOK')         #true
print isValidNumberPlate('GT5HYKU')         #false
```

Take a look [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html) for slicing that I am using in the example. [Demo](http://ideone.com/WBJStO)